# How to Integrate Icons into an Overflow Menu in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design, appbar, iconbutton

I'm working on a Flutter application and aim to achieve a design similar to the Material Design 3 overflow menu, as shown in the image below.

[image]

Here's my current code snippet for creating an AppBar with various icons:

```
  child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 202, 55),
              title: ResponsiveWeb(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  child: Row(
                    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                   children: [
                      Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            const Icon(
                              FontAwesomeIcons.checkDouble,
                              size: 25,
                              color: const Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                            ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      
                      ),
                      Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Tooltip(
                              message: 'Daily goals',
                              child: Semantics(
                                label: 'Pomodoro timer daily goals',
                                enabled: true,
                                readOnly: true,
                                child: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.military_tech_outlined,
                                    color: const Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                                    size: 25,
                                    
                                    semanticLabel: 'Pomodoro timer daily goals',
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) =>
                                              SettingsUIPomodoro()),
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Tooltip(
                              message: 'Settings',
                              child: Semantics(
                                label: 'Pomodoro timer settings',
                                enabled: true,
                                readOnly: true,
                                child: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.settings_outlined,
                                    color: const Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                                    size: 25,
                                    semanticLabel: 'Pomodoro timer Settings',
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) =>
                                              SettingsUIPomodoro()),
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Tooltip(
                              message: 'Analytics',
                              child: Semantics(
                                label: 'Pomodoro timer Analytics',
                                enabled: true,
                                readOnly: true,
                                child: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.show_chart_outlined,
                                    color: const Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                                    size: 25,
                                    semanticLabel: 'Pomodoro timer Analytics',
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) => Text('goal')),
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Tooltip(
                              message: 'Profile',
                              child: Semantics(
                                label: 'Pomodoro timer Profile',
                                enabled: true,
                                readOnly: true,
                                child: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.face_outlined,
                                    color: const Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                                    size: 25,
                                    semanticLabel: 'Pomodoro timer Profile',
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) => Profile()),
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Tooltip(
                              message: 'More',
                              child: Semantics(
                                label: 'Pomodoro timer More',
                                enabled: true,
                                readOnly: true,
                                child: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.more_vert_outlined,
                                    color: const Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                                    size: 25,
                                    semanticLabel: 'Pomodoro timer More',
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) => Profile()),
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

I specifically want to integrate the following two icons into the overflow menu icon, mirroring the design from Material 3:

- 'daily goals' icon (`Icons.military_tech_outlined`)
- 'analytics' icon (`Icons.show_chart_outlined`)

Here's how these icons are currently implemented:

```
child: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.military_tech_outlined,
                                    color: const Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                                    size: 25,
                                    
                                    semanticLabel: 'Pomodoro timer daily goals',
                                  ),

 child: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.show_chart_outlined,
                                    color: const Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                                    size: 25,
                                    semanticLabel: 'Pomodoro timer Analytics',
                                  ),
```

And I want to nest these inside the 'more' icon in my AppBar:

```
child: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.more_vert_outlined,
                                    color: const Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                                    size: 25,
                                    semanticLabel: 'Pomodoro timer More',
                                  ),
```

How can I nest these specific icons within the overflow menu icon, mimicking the Material Design 3 example?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Take a look at PopupMenuButton:https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PopupMenuButton-class.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can archive this using `popupMenubutton`.

> also check bellow links for more reference.
>
> [Example link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-pop-up-menu/)
>
> [Official flutter link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PopupMenuButton-class.html)

try this your edited code:

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 202, 55),
    title: SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Row(
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
            child: Row(
              children: const [
                Icon(
                  Icons.abc,
                  size: 25,
                  color: Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                ),
                Text.rich(
                  TextSpan(
                    text: ' pomo',
                    style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                        fontSize: 25,
                        color: Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                    children: <TextSpan>[
                      TextSpan(
                        text: 'work',
                        style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                            color: Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                            decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                            decorationThickness: 3,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                      ),
                      TextSpan(
                        text: 'o.com',
                        style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                            fontSize: 25,
                            color: Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Tooltip(
                  message: 'Settings',
                  child: Semantics(
                    label: 'Pomodoro timer settings',
                    enabled: true,
                    readOnly: true,
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.settings_outlined,
                        color: Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                        size: 25,
                        semanticLabel: 'Pomodoro timer Settings',
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) =>
                                  SettingsUIPomodoro()),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Tooltip(
                  message: 'Profile',
                  child: Semantics(
                    label: 'Pomodoro timer Profile',
                    enabled: true,
                    readOnly: true,
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.face_outlined,
                        color: Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                        size: 25,
                        semanticLabel: 'Pomodoro timer Profile',
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        /* Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => Profile()),
                        ); */
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
    actions: [
      PopupMenuButton(
          icon: Tooltip(
            message: 'More',
            child: Semantics(
              label: 'Pomodoro timer More',
              enabled: true,
              readOnly: true,
              child: const Icon(
                Icons.more_vert_outlined,
                color: Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                size: 25,
                semanticLabel: 'Pomodoro timer More',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          itemBuilder: ((context) => [
                PopupMenuItem(
                  child: Tooltip(
                    message: 'Daily goals',
                    child: Semantics(
                      label: 'Pomodoro timer daily goals',
                      enabled: true,
                      readOnly: true,
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.military_tech_outlined,
                          color: Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                          size: 25,
                          semanticLabel:
                              'Pomodoro timer daily goals',
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) =>
                                    SettingsUIPomodoro()),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                PopupMenuItem(
                  child: Tooltip(
                    message: 'Analytics',
                    child: Semantics(
                      label: 'Pomodoro timer Analytics',
                      enabled: true,
                      readOnly: true,
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.show_chart_outlined,
                          color: Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                          size: 25,
                          semanticLabel: 'Pomodoro timer Analytics',
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) =>
                                    const Text('goal')),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
              ),
        ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Here is the snippet for action in an appbar,

```dart
 actions: [
          IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.person)),
          IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.people_alt)),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              showMenu(
                context: context,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                position: const RelativeRect.fromLTRB(1, 80, 0, 0),
                items: [
                  PopupMenuItem(
                    child: const ListTile(
                      title: Text('Help Center'),
                      trailing: Icon(Icons.help),
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {},
                  ),
                  PopupMenuItem(
                    child: const ListTile(
                      title: Text('File a Bug'),
                      trailing: Icon(Icons.bug_report),
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {},
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.more_vert),
          ),
        ],
```